# Active directory want to use on win 7

Tags: active-directory

My server is completely crashed and i don't had backup of active directory. So i just created new directory with same name. but still users are not login through the domain. Error"The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed."

I tried By changing the DNS ipaddress in network adapter. But still it not getting login into domain. he

Then i try some tricksss .. i just remove user from domain and again add into the domain then i change. It shws message "welcome to domain"..after that i login as a AD Admin login in the pc after that i created a user there by browsing the name of the person and give him administrator rights.

Now when the user are login through new login id it create a new profile in the users.With no software installed as  first one.

As it is new user i know that the user had to install again all software.. but it is the long process....
IS THERE ANY METHOD BY WHICH THE OLD DIRECTORY USER CAN LOGIN INTO NEW DOMAIN WITHOUT CREATING NEW PROFILE OR IS THERE ANY METHOD TO MAP BOTH THE USERS BY WHICH THEY CAN USE INSTALLED SOFTWARE